# jQuery checkbox toggles all divs instead of only specific ones

Tags: ajax, html, toggle, jquery

My page displays divs containing posts. The divs have the following format (where you see # is the postID in my database):

```
<div id="post_#>
    <div id="post_#_inside">
        <div id="like_#">
        </div>
        <div id="dislike_#">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Every post_# also holds a class of like or dislike.

I also have two checkboxes. Their goal is to toggle all liked posts or all disliked posts.

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <p class="left"><input id="show_likes" name="show_likes" type="checkbox" value="1" class="choice"/>
    <label for="b1">Hide Liked</label></p>

    <p class="right"><input id="show_dislikes" name="show_dislikes" type="checkbox" value="1" class="choice"/>
    <label for="b1">Hide Disliked</label></p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

My problem is that the jQuery I have hides ALL posts, regardless of their class. Obviously, I want only the Hide Liked checkbox to hide posts with class="like" and the Hide Disliked checkbox to hide only posts with class="dislike". Also, when I click the checkbox again, the post div does return, but the content inside the div remains hidden (I get the div with the backgrounds but no text).

My jQuery:

```
//When Hide Liked checkbox clicked, toggle all liked contests.
$("input[name*='show_likes']").click(function() {
    if ($('[id^=post_]').is('.like')) {
        $('[id^=post_]').toggle();
    }
});

//When Hide Disliked checkbox clicked, toggle all disliked contests.
$("input[name*='show_dislikes']").click(function() {
    if ($('[id^=post_]').is('.dislike')) {
        $('[id^=post_]').toggle();
    }
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?
    });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needed to loop through your selector instead of just applying the toggle to all matches:

```
$("input[name*='show_likes']").click(function() {
    $('[id^=post_]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is('.like')) {
            $(this).toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

But then, why do that when you can just `.filter()` out the unwanted elements?

```
$("input[name*='show_likes']").click(function() {
    $('[id^=post_]').filter('.like').toggle();
});
```

Comment: @Jonathan `$('[id^=post_].like').toggle();` is more efficient. The first block at this answer would be recommended if you want to perform more complex operations, though.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code checks whether the any element starting with ID `post_` contains class `.like`. Then, you create a new jQuery object, selecting all elements with `id^=post_`, and using `toggle`.

Instead of using `.is('.like')`, extend your selector with `.like`.
The code below solves your issue:

```
$("input[name*='show_likes']").click(function() {
    $('[id^=post_].like').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Quick correction on .is(), it checks every element in the selection, so if ANY element in the selection matches, it will return true. http://docs.jquery.com/Is

Answer (score 0):

.is() checks every element, so when you call

```
if ($('[id^=post_]').is('.like')) {
    $('[id^=post_]').toggle();
}
```

if any one of the elements that have an ID that start with post_ also has the class of like, then all of the elements will be toggled. You also re-query the DOM, so even if you filtered by elements with a class of like, all post_ would still be toggled.

A more appropriate solution would be just to query your likes

```
$( ".like" ).toggle();
```

reference: http://docs.jquery.com/Is

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#show_likes').click(function(){ $('.like').toggle(); });
```

I think something like that would work for you.

However you may want to consider something more robust. What if the user navigates to the control with TAB and then uses the space bar to check the box?

Also you may want to consider not using .toggle() if there is a chance that the initial state of the check box may end up out of sync with the initial display state of the posts.

Comment: You're right. I'm thinking of changing the checkbox to be a custom button instead, we'll see